# How can I set order by asc/desc dynamically from a link

Tags: php, mysql, href

I would like to be able to dynamically change the ordering of a set of rows from ascending to descending and vice versa.

Something like `<a href="file.php?sort=">` and after a click sort="asc" , after another click sort="desc" so i can get it with `$_GET` and put it on variable to use it in mysql query.

This is some of my code

```
if(isset($_SESSION['is_logged']) === true)
{
    $url_array      =   array("date_added", "username", "title", "content");

    $order          =   "date_added";
    if (isset($_GET['order_by']) && in_array($order, $url_array))
    {
        $order      =   $_GET['order_by'];
    }

    echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">';
    echo '<tr>Sort: &#x25BC; <br />'
                . '<th><a href="?order_by=date_added&type=">somestuff</a></th>'
                . '<th><a href="?order_by=username">somestuff</a></th>'
                . '<th><a href="?order_by=title">somestuff</a></th>'
                . '<th><a href="?order_by=content">somestuff</a></th>'
        . '</tr>';


    $query          =   run_q('SELECT * FROM posts as p, users as u WHERE p.added_by=u.user_id ORDER BY '.$order.' DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your hyperlinks aren;t directing to any particular page, just a query string.

Try this:

```
echo '<tr>Sort: &#x25BC; <br />'
            . '<th><a href="'.$_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'?order_by=date_added&type=">somestuff</a></th>'
            . '<th><a href="'.$_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'?order_by=username">somestuff</a></th>'
            . '<th><a href="'.$_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'?order_by=title">somestuff</a></th>'
            . '<th><a href="'.$_SERVER[PHP_SELF].'?order_by=content">somestuff</a></th>'
    . '</tr>';
```

Also your query is susceptible to injection SQL attacks, so change your `$order` variable to this:

```
$order = ($order == ("date_added" || "username" || "title" || "content") ? $_GET['order_by'] : "date_added");
```

That also has the benefit of reducing the previous `$order = "date_added"` line.